# In a large MapReduce job with "X" mappers and "Y" reducers, how many distinct copy operations will there be in the sort/shuffle phase

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

As I understand there will be X + Y  copy operations , correct me if im wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each reducer, in worst case might fetch the records from all mappers, assuming its keys are there in all the mappers available. That would give X copies for one reducer in worst case. That would lead to XY operations rather than X+Y.